# Регулярные выражения JAVA ,замена символов и чистка текста

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Помогите кто знает "регулярные выражения".

Нужна сама регулярка , у меня есть метод для чистки текста , можно 2 разных регулярки для каждого варианта.

Сделать :

1.В середине текста, если есть несколько новых строк подряд - нужно оставить только одну.

**Было:**

`<br/>\n<br/>\nCума&nbsp;`

**Ожидается:**

`<br/>\nCума&nbsp;`

как это сделать во всём тексте?

2.Несколько `<br><br>` подряд в тексте заменить на `<br>` и как учесть закрытые `<br/>`

и так же заменить в одной регулярке , `<br/><br/>` заменить на `<br/>` , если это возможно?

можно поочерёдно регулярки , чтоб читаемо было.

хорошим вопросом будет, как заменить два одинаковых (повторяющихся символа в тексте ) на один такой символ.

Спасибо .
Всем удачи с кодом!

Comment: Неужели вы сами ничего не попробовали подставить в `replaceAll`? Тут всё, что нужно, это подмаска и 2 квантификатора, остальное уже есть в вопросе.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew , добрый день, естественно пробовал сам и много раз, у меня стоит задача не только сделать , то что я описал в вопросе, регулярку написал которая просто ищет совпадение в тексте с заданными символами и удаляет их, ещё удаляет в строке  `<br>` и пробелы, но не получается , написать , чтоб заменить два одинаковых символа одним , в любой части текста ...вот моя регулярка `\\n<br/>|(<br>\s*)?$)` , но она не верно выполняет условие поиска несколько новых строк , заменить одной и сюда же учесть, чтоб несколько одинаковых символов <br><br> заменить одним <br>, спасибо за помощь!

Comment: `.replaceAll("(<br/?>\n)+", "$1").replaceAll("(?:<br/?>)+", "<br/>")`? Или `.replaceAll("(<br/?>\n)+|(<br/?>)+", "$1$2")`?

Comment: Станислав, сработало?